# The use of apostrophes when there is no clear owner

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe

Is this sentence correct and if so/not, why?

The cyclist's average speed is less than that of a car's.

Comment: Where is there no clear owner?

Comment: yes it's correct.

Comment: The double possessive is unnecessary-to-distinctly-iffy in this example; stick with 'that of a car'. The statement is also clumsy, coordinating 'cyclist' with 'car'.

Comment: Please include the research that you have done.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Apostrophes may be used to show (b) associative as well as (a) ownership relationships:

(a) *Fred's bike*

(b) *the bike's back wheel*

(although there is a move to drop the apostrophe from associative relationships: nine days wonder / travellers cheques / working mens clubs / Achilles heel / childrens clothing [generic])

*But* (2) There are restrictions on the use of the 'double possessive' (a book of Fred's). The following is by [Mignon Fogarty](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/double-possessives) [reformatted]:

> [T]o help us learn what’s right, let’s look at some possessives and
> double possessives that native speakers *wouldn't* use.
>
> It definitely sounds odd to say, “a car of Squiggly.” On the other
> hand, you could say, “a car of Squiggly's,” assuming he has lots of
> cars and you’re pointing out one of them. However, “a car of
> Squiggly's” doesn’t sound as natural to me as “one of Squiggly's
> cars.”
>
> On the other hand, it’s perfectly normal to say, “the Crown Jewels of
> the United Kingdom” or “the United Kingdom’s Crown Jewels,” but it
> turns out that it’s ungrammatical to say, “the Crown Jewels of the
> United Kingdom’s.”
>
> Here’s a clear-cut rule that helps explain this:
>
> **When you’re talking about inanimate objects—objects that aren’t alive,
> such as “the United Kingdom”—you can’t use a double possessive.**
>
> According to The New Fowler's Modern English Usage, for a double
> possessive to be legal, the object of the preposition “of” has to be
> “definite and human.” In other words, it’s fine to say, “a friend of
> my uncle’s” but not “a friend of the museum’s.” You have to say, “a
> friend of the museum.”
>
> However, according to this rule, it would be OK
> to say, “He's a friend of a friend’s,” but we’ve all heard the common
> expression “a friend of a friend.” I guess double possessives don’t
> always work. That should make some sticklers happy.