# four books' long

Tags: apostrophe

I read this in a very respectable article:

*The Apologos of Odysseus, four books' long, is...*

Please do not dismiss this usage out of hand.  I have never seen the apostrophe used like this before and am aware that *four books long* is much more common.  I would like to know the reason for it, though, assuming that the august author did not make a mistake on the first page of his article.

I assume that the same author would not dream of writing "four feet's long" *vel sim*.
It is the status of *long* as an adjective that makes it tricky.  "Four days' work", for example, makes perfect sense.

The question, therefore, is: Is this a known usage to you and how can it be explained?

Comment: Can you please link to the article?

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1192503?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

I don't know if it is accessible outside my Uni.  You will see that I changed it a bit for ease.  How about a longer excerpt:
"Crucial to any persuasive reading of the Odyssey is a coherent account of the Apologos of Odysseus, his recitation to the Phaiakians, four books' long, of the startling things that happened to him after his departure from Troy."

Comment: Thanks, that helps set the context. I'd say the apostrophe is unnecessary there and probably a mistake. It would be required if it was "four books' *worth*".

Comment: for sure, worth of course being a noun, avoiding the problem.  I am hoping for some rationalisation of the author's choice, which I am very hesitant to call a mistake!

Comment: Not necessarily a mistake, but an affectation.

Comment: I wonder if it may have had something to do with the type-setting?

Comment: Coo, Hot Licks. Aren't you being a lot generous, passing that clear mistake off as an affectation?

Comment: '...worth of course being a noun, avoiding the problem' Don't you believe it. There are _dogs homes_ and _dogs' homes_ (of the institutional variety) in the UK, and more _working mens clubs_ than _working men's clubs_. Even _nine days wonder_ [[the use of apostrophes when there is no clear owner](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286199/the-use-of-apostrophes-when-there-is-no-clear-owner/286207#286207)] seems to be gradually dropping the apostrophe.

Comment: I maintain that the nominal status of "worth" avoids the problem raised by my question, even if a related area of usage throws up those other questions.

Comment: The article may look respectable to the unpracticed eye, but it shows multiple signs of  having reached publication without the benefit of professional copyediting. Moreover, any writer capable of putting needless quotation marks around the word _meaning_ in the phrase "and about the ‘meaning’ communicated by narrative structures in general" is more than capable of attaching a needless apostrophe to the word _books_ in the simple phrase "four books long."

Comment: It's probably a typo.

Answer (score 1):

> The Apologos of Odysseus, four books' long, is...
>
> Please do not dismiss this usage out of hand.

And yet it deserves to be dismissed out of hand.

What follows the genitive should be a noun of some sort as the genitive acts as a determiner. "Long" is not a noun - it is an adjective. The Apologos of Odysseus, *which is* four books long,

*four books' long = *The long of four books.

four books' worth/length = The worth/length of four books.

Comment: But 'four books long' models on 'four yards wide' and there are plenty of examples of the form 'n books long' / 'n episodes long'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why have you avoided the genitive?

Comment: The expression 'x yards/metres/feet/foot/mm ... high/long/wide/deep' doesn't use the Saxon genitive. [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wide). There **is** the strange case of << nine days wonder >> where day, days and days' are all still in use.

Answer (score -2):

Sven Yargs commented:

> The article may look respectable to the unpracticed eye, but it shows multiple signs of having reached publication without the benefit of professional copyediting. Moreover, any writer capable of putting needless quotation marks around the word meaning in the phrase "and about the ‘meaning’ communicated by narrative structures in general" is more than capable of attaching a needless apostrophe to the word *books* in the simple phrase "four books long."